# Youtube not loading completely in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html, youtube, webpage

Dont know why youtube is not loading completely in chrome.It was working fine till yesterday.Few screenshots are [normal zoom pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Auju9.png) and [zoom:50%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzQ8Q.png).My internet speed is fine as all other sites are opening normally, further youtube is also working well when I am it opening it with microsoft edge but really not getting why it is not loading completely in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

- In the command prompt run: ipconfig /flushdns
- If possible, delete all browsing history/cookies from Chrome
- Disable ad-block or similar programs.

Once done see if it loads properly. If not, try to uninstall/reinstall chrome if that is an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with adblock filters.Updating them should fix the problem.